# sympy: How do I taylor expand each factor of an expression?

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math, polynomials

I have been struggling to taylor expand. I have a complicating expression which is of the form: P(x,y)*Q(x,y)*.../(K(x,y)*L(x,y)*....) where the capital letters are polynomials wrt x and y. If I taylor expand it with respect to x and y, the program does not work.

I would like to taylor expand each factor polynomial individually and then multiply and divide them and do a second taylor expansion hoping that the program will work.

My function is this: `D*(-c3*(k**3*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + 2*k**2*p**2 + k*p**3*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta)) + (c1*(k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2) + 2*c2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta))*(k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2))*(-c3*(-2*cos_psi*k**2*p*q - cos_theta*k**3*q - cos_theta*k*q*(-2*cos_psi*p*q + p**2 + q**2) + k**3*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + k**2*p**2 + k**2*q**2 + k**2*(-2*cos_psi*p*q + p**2 + q**2) + k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta)*(-2*cos_psi*p*q + p**2 + q**2))/2 + (c1*(-2*cos_psi*p*q - 2*cos_theta*k*q + k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2 + q**2) - 2*c2*cos_theta*k*q + 2*c2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta))*(-2*cos_psi*p*q - 2*cos_theta*k*q + k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2 + q**2)/2)*(2*k**4*kappa + kappa*(k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2)**2 + kappa*(-2*cos_psi*p*q - 2*cos_theta*k*q + k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2 + q**2)**2)*(c1*q**2/2 + c2*cos_psi*p*q + c2*cos_theta*k*q - c2*k**2 - 2*c2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) - c2*p**2 + c3*cos_psi**2*p**2 + 2*c3*cos_psi*cos_theta*k*p - c3*cos_psi*p*q/2 + c3*cos_theta**2*k**2 - c3*cos_theta*k*q/2 - c3*k**2/2 - c3*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) - c3*p**2/2)/(k**2*kappa*(k**4*kappa + kappa*(k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2)**2)*(k**4*kappa + kappa*(-2*cos_psi*p*q - 2*cos_theta*k*q + k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2 + q**2)**2)*(kappa*(k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2)**2 + kappa*(-2*cos_psi*p*q - 2*cos_theta*k*q + k**2 + 2*k*p*((sin_theta·cos_phi)*sin_psi + cos_psi*cos_theta) + p**2 + q**2)**2))`

You can display it using `display` from IPython.display import display.

Comment: You can then use the sympy library to taylor expand each factor polynomial before the divide.

Comment: how do I extract each factor polynomial from this expression?

Comment: First, you should separate the expression into its individual factors. That way, you can Taylor expand each factor separately. For example, you could separate the expression into D * P * Q * K * L * etc. Then, you can Taylor expand each factor separately. For example, for P, you could do P = P(x,y) + P'(x,y) * x + P''(x,y) * x^2 + P'''(x,y) * x^3 + etc. Then, you would do the same for Q, K, L, etc. Once you have Taylor expanded each factor, you can then multiply and divide them and do a second Taylor expansion. This should help the program to work

Comment: That's what I want to do. But how do I separate the expression into its individual factors. That's what I am asking, sorry if I am unclear.

Comment: Please include some code that sets up an example of what you want to do. It doesn't have to be a real example but just dumping a load of output into SO does not make anything reproducible. Also I don't see any x or y in the expression.